# Window Layer Transition on iOS 9 not working as expected in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Below code is expected to do a custom transition from current viewcontroller to destination viewcontroller. It works as expected in iOS 10 but on iOS 9, it transition **from current to current view controller** and then in the end of transition animation, it quickly changes to destination viewcontroler.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
let destVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: dest)
present(destVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why would you add a _window transition_ if what you're trying to do is _present_ a view controller? What _are_ you trying to do? If you are trying to do a push-from-right presentation, then do a custom presentation animation and do it right.

Comment: It is helping me with the custom animation while transitioning between view controllers.

Comment: But that is not how you do a custom animation while transitioning between view controllers. There is a right way to do a custom presentation animation. Use that way.